# Json() in MVC converts datetime to UTC automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonserializer

I am already storing UTC time in DateTime objects.

When I send this across using Json() serializer these dates are again converted to UTC. I don't want this to happen.

Please help.

Comment: Check the Kind property of your DateTime objects, maybe they are not marked as UTC then they get converted again.

Comment: You are right. Please add this as a answer so that I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Kind` property of your `DateTime` objects, maybe they are not marked as UTC then they get converted again.

Comment: Where is this 'Kind' property? What should it look like?

Comment: @jao it's a property of `DateTime` objects has, for example: `var date = DateTime.Now; Console.WriteLine(date.Kind.ToString());`